if "always headers response table" includes 2xx, how it can not be a super set of "onsuccess"?
apache official documentaion says that:

• "onsuccess (default)" responses headers table → just for 2xx responses • "always"
responses headers table → for all responses including 2xx

later it says:

always is not a superset of onsuccess

if "always headers response table" includes 2xx, how it can not be a super set of "onsuccess"?
please consider that i've red full document so please do not repeat quotes of apache documents, i need answer not quotings :), thanks for your time

You missed an import part of the statement

always is not a superset of onsuccess with respect to existing headers:

It is a little confusing, but if you read the documentation you linked to it does explain it.

This difference between onsuccess and always is a feature that resulted as a consequence of how httpd internally stores headers for a HTTP response, since it does not offer any "normalized" single list of headers.

example
Here's my attempt to make the example from the docs more clear:
step 1 - Your Application
   response.status = 200
   response.headers['X-Foo'] = 'bar'
   return response

step 2: mod_proxy
mod_proxy sets headers in the always table and not in the default onSuccess table
apache header tables:



Always
onSuccess




x-Foo: bar




step 3: mod_headers
Header onSuccess set X-Foo: baz

apache header tables:



Always
onSuccess




x-Foo: bar
X-Foo: baz



step 4: server response
HTTP/1.1 200 
 Server: apache
 x-Foo: bar
 X-Foo: baz

summary
That's the reason the doc state

always is not a superset of onsuccess with respect to existing headers.

and that

repeating this directive with both conditions makes sense in some scenarios

Again from the example, you can resolve the issue with:
mod_headers
Header always     unset X-Foo
Header onSuccess  set   X-Foo: baz


if you refer to "existing headers" as "x-foo", that still doesn't change anything, why? because if x-foo→baz in always, it will be in all responses (2xx and all other responses) and anything actually doesn't change ! god bless me! my mind is gonna below up on this!!!!!

first off, thanks, after that, i think, in Header onSuccess  set   X-Foo: baz line of your provided code, we don't need : so simply just remove it, last but most important thing: i can not still accept your answer, what do you mean of "with respect to existing headers"? the example you provided doesn't clarify anything to me, still "always" is a superset of "onsuccess", i'll appreciate if you can provide an example that can show us "onsuccess" table used while "always" not, that is the case that can show us "always" is not a superset of "onsuccess"

The example is showing that setting an onsuccess header with mod_header won’t override an existing header. Both bar and baz are returned. That’s generally not the desired behavior. If you had set the header with “always” it would override it, and only baz would be returned.

Why do you say you don’t need “onSuccess set X-Foo: baz”? That’s kind of the whole point of the example. When you DO want to set onsuccess headers with mod_headers, this is an edge case you need to be aware of.

i think that i can understand you now, since header set will override previous set of a certain header, so if "onsuccess" was a subset of "always" we couldn't have sth like: x-foo: baz and x-foo: bar simultaneously, so thank you and i will accept your answer since it is solving my problem

i think that i can understand @ben now, since header set will override previous set of a certain header, so if "onsuccess" was a subset of "always" we couldn't have sth like: x-foo: baz and x-foo: bar simultaneously
so the example provided by @ben actually was an example that can show us "onsuccess" table used while "always" not, because
• while we don't use any existing header it's like:

• but when you use it will be like:

finally since they are actually different set of headers, maybe it's better to demonstrate this like a 3d drawing, why? because they actually don't cover each-other, they are two set of headers a response go through before going to physical wire

